# FRROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 483: Forbidden in yt-dlp

Tags: yt-dlp

Anyone can solve this error? When I change server it's worked but in my older server still not working I have tried rm cache too; but still. Maybe ip blocked by YouTube?

FRROR: unable to download video data: HTTP Error 483: Forbidden

Comment: Maybe your IP is blacklisted. Anyway, this is off-topic here, take a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)